# Update treeview without duplicates

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, treeview

I have two `TreeView`.
The first one is designed like this :

```
A
|--B1
   |--C1
   |--C2
|--B2
   |--C3
|--B3
```

The second one is empty.

I implemented a Drag and Drop system so the user can drag from my first tree view to the second one to fill it.
When a node is dragged into the `TreeView` I want it to bring all his parents and child nodes. **Not the siblings**.

Example :

If I drag `C2`, my second `TreeView` should look like this

```
A
|--B1
   |--C2
```

If I decide to add `C1` too, it should look like this :

```
A
|--B1
   |--C1
   |--C2
```

I don't want a duplicate like this :

```
 A
|--B1
   |--C2
 A
|--B1
   |--C1
```

So I have two questions from here (considering the drag and drop is already implemented like [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307968) and only adds the selected node without the parents or child).

- How can I bring the node with is child and parents but not the siblings. Is it even possible ?
- Once the first question is answered and I have an algorithm to add a node with all parents and child nodes, how can I update with a sibling without re-writing the whole tree twice ?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same task when writing a gui for some torrent client.
When opening a torrent the tree view with files and folder included to torrent should be show.
How do i solve it:
I've got a List of file pathes and first what I do I've sorted it and then adding items of sorted list to with this function to treeview

```
void FileTreeModel::addPath( QString path,QString size )
{
path=QDir::toNativeSeparators(path);
QStringList pathparts=path.split(QDir::separator());

FileTreeItem *iterator=rootItem,*save=rootItem;
if (rootItem->childCount()==0)
{
    //qDebug() << "root item has no childs appending current path";
    FileTreeItem* curitem=rootItem;
    for (int i=0;i<pathparts.count();i++)
    {
        curitem->appendChild(new FileTreeItem(qMakePair(pathparts.at(i),i==pathparts.count()-1? size : ""),curitem));
        curitem = curitem->child(0);
    }
    rootItem=save;
    return;
}
for (int i=0;i<pathparts.count();i++)
{
    int foundnum=-1;
    for (int j=0;j<iterator->childCount();j++)
    {
        //qDebug() << iterator->child(j)->data(0) << " " << pathparts.at(i);
        if (iterator->child(j)->data(0).toString().compare(pathparts.at(i))==0) 
        {
            //qDebug() <<"Found :" << iterator->child(j)->data(0) << " " << pathparts.at(i);
            foundnum=j;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (foundnum >= 0)
    {
        iterator = iterator->child(foundnum);
    }
    else
    {
        //qDebug() << "appending new child" << pathparts.at(i)  << " to "  << iterator->data(0) ;
        iterator->appendChild(new FileTreeItem(qMakePair(pathparts.at(i),i==pathparts.count()-1? size : ""),iterator));
        iterator = iterator->child(iterator->childCount()-1);
        //qDebug() << "new iterator value" << iterator->data(0) ;
    }

}
    rootItem=save;

}
```

It is Qt but i think you can understand the idea.

Comment: This is a little to specific for your situation. And in a language with a technology i've never used. I kinda get the idea but still can't find a way to translate this for my situation. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Change your `TreeViewDragDrop` on your destination `Treeview`:

```
private void treeView_DragDrop(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
{
    TreeNode NewNode;

    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode", false))
    {
        NewNode = (TreeNode)e.Data.GetData("System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode");
        if (!(sender as TreeView).Nodes.Contains(NewNode))
        {
            //Add the droped node 
            List<TreeNode> tt = new List<TreeNode>();
            TreeNode tn = (TreeNode)NewNode.Clone();
            tt.Add(tn);

            //Prepare node with it's parents until the root note
            while ((TreeNode)NewNode.Parent is TreeNode)
            {
                TreeNode tnp = (TreeNode)NewNode.Parent.Clone();

                //prevent siblings to be added
                tnp.Nodes.Clear();

                tt.Add(tnp);
                NewNode = NewNode.Parent;
            }

            //Construct the structure of the treenote to be added to the treeview
            for (int i = tt.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                tt[i].Nodes.Add(tt[i - 1]);
            }

            /*Add the whole structured treenode to the treeview*/


            TreeNode rootnote = ExistNotes((sender as TreeView), tt[tt.Count - 1]);
            if (rootnote != null)//Root node exists, add to the existing node
            {
                foreach (TreeNode tsub in tt[tt.Count - 1].Nodes)
                {
                    AddNote(rootnote, tsub);
                }
            }
            else//Root node not exist, add to the treeview as new node.
            {
                (sender as TreeView).Nodes.Add(tt[tt.Count - 1]);
            }

            //  NewNode.Remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Supportive functions:

```
/// <summary>
/// Recursive function to add node
/// </summary>
/// <param name="tnbase">RootNode</param>
/// <param name="tn">Node to be added</param>
private void AddNode(TreeNode tnbase, TreeNode tn)
{
    bool exists = false;
    foreach (TreeNode rt in tnbase.Nodes)
    {
        if (this.IsNodesEquals(rt, tn))
        {
            foreach (TreeNode srt in tn.Nodes)
            {
                this.AddNode(rt, srt);
            }
            exists = true;
        }
    }
    if (!exists)
    {
        tnbase.Nodes.Add(tn);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Get exist node from the treeview
/// </summary>
/// <param name="tv">Treeview to check</param>
/// <param name="tn">Node to compare</param>
/// <returns></returns>
private TreeNode ExistNode(TreeView tv, TreeNode tn)
{
    TreeNode existsnote = null;
    foreach (TreeNode rt in tv.Nodes)
    {
        if (this.IsNodesEquals(rt, tn))
        {
            existsnote = rt;
        }
    }
    return existsnote;
}

/// <summary>
/// Compare two nodes by the text
/// </summary>
/// <param name="t1">node to compare</param>
/// <param name="t2">node to compare with</param>
/// <returns></returns>
private bool IsNodesEquals(TreeNode t1, TreeNode t2)
{
    return (t1 != null && t2 != null && t1.Text == t2.Text);
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use your IsNodesEquals method. Here's an example where it won't work: suppose you have a tree of directories, and the Text property of the node is the FileName property of the directory. You can have two directories named "bin" one inside the other, so that the text is the same and not the objects. You should use the Tag property as it is left to the user to define it. Personnaly, I use the DirectoryInfo class as Tag in this particular case so that the test would probe.